# Web Page code to mute all desktop application

Tags: javascript, media-player, html, volume, audio

Is there a way to implement web page code that when surfing to it, it can mute all desktop applications running on the client machine? Or there are permissions level that won't allow doing that? Maybe it requires for me to implement some browser plugin (or existing one) to get that access?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or there are permissions level that won't allow doing that?

No, it is not possible for a web site to turn down the system volume or influence it in any other way - and thank goodness for that. It used to be possible to have full-screen web sites (if that's what you mean by "mute"), but that has gone due to problems with fraud.

Comment: how about browsers plugins? If I'll force plugin download or something?

Comment: @user You'd have to specify for which browsers on which platforms you want this. There's unlikely to be one plugin for every browser.

Comment: I see - assuming the desktop runs Windows 7 and the explorer is either Chrome or IE8\9 can I write plugin that once downloaded has control over applications volume?

Comment: @user you probably can, but it's going to be a lot of work and the user will have to install it. What programming languages can you use?

Comment: Thanks @Pekka. I'm still in the abstract level, just verifying if (and how) there is a way to do this volume control, and what will be the easiest way for user deployment.. you say lot of work since these are hard scripts for plugins or other perspective?

Comment: Writing browser plugins is not easy, especially ones that try to access system settings. The user will have to grant the plugin access to the system, which most users won't do. It's a crazy amount of hassle